# send a json containing a big buffer (bytearray) through sockets: gets truncated

Tags: python, arrays, json, sockets

I'm trying to send a json containing text fields and a buffer in a bytearray, from a micro-controller to a Windows server

```py
msg = {"some_stuff": "some_stuff", "buf": bytearray(b'\xfe\xc2\xf1\xfe\xd5\xc0 ...')}
```

Note that **the buffer is quite long** (so that I can't put it here as reference) `len(buf) -> 35973`

I'm sending the length of the message before to the server so that it knows how long is the message to be received

```py
def send_json(conn, msg):
    msg = json.dumps(msg).encode('utf-8')
    msg_length = len(msg)
    header = str(msg_length).encode('utf-8')
    header += b' ' * (64 - len(header))
    conn.send(header)
    conn.send(msg)
```

The receiving function is then

```py
def receive_json(conn) -> dict:
    msg_length = int(
        conn.recv(64).decode('utf-8').replace(' ', '')
    )
    msg_b = conn.recv(msg_length)
    msg_s = msg_b.decode('utf-8')
    try:
        msg_d = json.loads(msg_s)
    except:
        msg_d = eval(msg_s)
    return msg_d
```

The problem is that **the received message is truncated**.

```
msg_b = b'{"buf": bytearray(b\'\\xfe\\xc2\\xf1 ... \\x06u\\xd0\\xff\\xb'
```

It's worth mentioning that while in debug, if I stop for a while with a breakpoint on line `msg_b = conn.recv(msg_length)`, before running it, the received message is complete.

So **it seems that in the receiving function the `conn.recv(msg_length)` instruction does not wait to receive a message of the specified length** (`msg_length`)

Why is it the case? What can I do to receive a complete message?

I could introduce `time.sleep` between receiving the length of the message and the message, but how to know how much to wait depending on the message length?

Thank you

Comment: you should run `loop` to read all data because socket doesn't have to send all in one chunk. System (not Python) may also use smaller buffer (i.e. 8096 bytes) and sends/receives it in partially.

Comment: `msg_length` informs socket only what `max size` you expect but if socket has smaller data then it gives you smaller result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was to check for how much of the message is missing and iterate till the message is complete

```py
def receive_json(conn) -> dict:
    msg_length = int(
        conn.recv(64).decode('utf-8').replace(' ', '')
    )
    buf = bytearray(b'')
    while len(buf) < msg_length:
        missing_length = msg_length - len(buf)
        packet = conn.recv(missing_length)
        buf.extend(packet)
    msg_s = buf.decode('utf-8')
    try:
        msg_d = json.loads(msg_s)
    except:
        msg_d = eval(msg_s)
    return msg_d
```

Comment: and this is standard method when you read from socket - you can see something similar in many programs

Comment: You still have the exact same problem with the length `conn.recv(64)` <- might receive the length AND part of the message in the same call

Answer (score 1):

TCP is a streaming protocol that guarantees delivery of bytes in the order sent, but not with the same send breaks.  You need to define a protocol (which you have, as a 64-byte header of message size, then the message data), and then buffer reads until you have a complete message.

Python sockets have a `.makefile` method that handles the buffering for you, where you can `.read(n)` a specific number of bytes or `.readline()` to read a newline-terminated line.  With this you can implement the following client and server:

**server.py**

```py
import socket
import json
import time

s = socket.socket()
s.bind(('',5000))
s.listen()

while True:
    c,a = s.accept()
    print(f'{a} connected')
    # wrap socket in a file-like buffer
    with c, c.makefile('rb') as r: # read binary so .read(n) gets n bytes
        while True:
            header = r.readline() # read header up to a newline
            if not header: break  # if empty string, client closed connection
            size = int(header)
            data = json.loads(r.read(size)) # read exactly "size" bytes and decode JSON
            print(f'{a}: {data}')
    print(f'{a} disconnected')
```

**client.py**

```py
import socket
import json

def send_json(conn, msg):
    # smaller data size if non-ASCII used.
    data = json.dumps(msg, ensure_ascii=False).encode()
    msg_length = len(data) # length in encoded bytes
    # send newline-terminated header, then data
    conn.sendall(f'{msg_length}\n'.encode())
    conn.sendall(data)

s = socket.socket()
s.connect(('localhost',5000))
with s:
    send_json(s, {'name':'马克'})  # check to support non-ASCII properly
    send_json(s, [1,2,3])
```

Start server.py, then run client.py a couple of times:

Output:

```
('127.0.0.1', 26013) connected
('127.0.0.1', 26013): {'name': '马克'}
('127.0.0.1', 26013): [1, 2, 3]
('127.0.0.1', 26013) disconnected
('127.0.0.1', 26015) connected
('127.0.0.1', 26015): {'name': '马克'}
('127.0.0.1', 26015): [1, 2, 3]
('127.0.0.1', 26015) disconnected
```